# Unmarshalling Bundle parsel in another device

Tags: android, bundle, marshalling, unmarshalling, parsel

I have to put some information in to bundle. Then i'm using `parsel` and saving to `SQlite` in the blob.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream valueStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ContentValues rows = new ContentValues();
            rows.put("name", name);
            Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();



            bundle.writeToParcel(p, 0);

            valueStream.write(p.marshall());
            rows.put("bundle", valueStream.toByteArray());

            db.insert("tableName", null, rows);

            valueStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error writing object", e.toString());
        }
```

Then in another Activity i'm reading the bundle:

```
 byte[] byteArray  = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Base.BUNDLE));


    Parcel parcel =  Parcel.obtain();
    parcel.unmarshall(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);
    Bundle bundle = Bundle.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);

    desc.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("key"));
```

In the same device operation is working well, but if i take a db file and take it to another device i will have error in reading code:

```
  desc.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("key"));
```

Unmarshalling unknown type code 7340147 at offset 12

can any budy tell me something about this?

Answer (score 1):

`Parcel` class uses various `native` methods to manipulate data which in this case used for storage.`native` basically mean using `c/c++` which is platform and architectural dependent in this case and which is not optimized to provide storage structure for various platforms but it is optimized to store data efficiently on local hardware which is your current device in this case.[link to docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)

So your parcel storage data may or may not work on other devices so if you want consistency then the alternatives are `Serializable` interface or `Json` object.

Answer (score 0):

> Then i'm parsel it and saving to SQlite in the blob.

That will be unlikely to work on one device, let alone more than one.

Quoting [the documentation for `Parcel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html), with emphasis added:

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, **it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage**: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Use some other serialization mechanism, one that you control and can ensure works across multiple devices and OS versions: JSON, XML, protobuf, etc.